# Emulating a blocking function call over a Queing Interface such as JMS in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, jms, blocking, nonblocking

I have processing engine which is ONLY available to me (exposed) through a Queing interface.

I would like to abstract away the Que based interface to one that is a simple blocking interface that can be called concurrently by multiple threads.

This interface will be called roughly 500 times a second from a single JVM process.

The question at a high level is: How does one transform a Que based interface into thread safe blocking function call in Java.

Notes:

1. I put the request on a Request_Q
2. The request is a JSON object of the form where I generate a unique id and the payload is the message I want processed:

   {id:1234567890, payload:"foo"}
3. After the engine is done processing this request it places the response on the queue Response_Q
4. The response message is of the same form as the request object except that the payload corresponds to the processed message and the id is the same as the request object. For example the response to the said request object could look like:

   {id:1234567890, payload:"bar"}
5. I pop the message of the Response_Q

I wish to encapsulate this queue based processing system in a traditional blocking function call of the following form:

```
public String process (String payload) {

   JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
   request.set("id", /* ... some way to generate a random key */ );
   request.set("payload", payload);

   // push the request onto Request_Q

   // Question
   // What is an elegant way to organize the code from here down?
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What's your problem? What's the point of using queues if you're just going to block the whole thing?

Comment: The underlying computation engine is only available to me as a Request and Response Q.

Comment: @Falmarri I have made some changes to the question. However I was not sure if your comment implied stylistic shortcomings in my question or did you think the problem posed is trivial. I have tried to address shortcoming in style. I think the problem is self evident.

Answer (score 1):

While I think you might be better off figuring out how to make your code non-blocking instead of blocking the queue, here's one way to do it:

In your process() method, set up a loop that peeks at the queue, and only exits when it finds the response to the message that was sent in that method invocation. This will be very inefficient, but I don't think that there's an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Well I typically implement this by using a wait/notify scheme which works pretty well. I wanted to see if the design gurus out there have perfected a transform to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

- Create a background thread that reads from the response_q
- Create a global `Map<String, Queue>` that the response thread has access to

**In the blocking function**

1. add new entry to the map, with request id as key and a new queue as value, it it this  request's private queue
2. write to the request_q
3. wait for response in private_q
4. when available, remove the map entry and return the response read from queue

**In the background thread, in an infinite loop**

1. read response from the global response_q
2. extract id from response
3. identify private queue from the global map
4. write to private queue

Some synchronization is required. Explore better data structure for the private queue.

**Update**

As `msandiford` commented, use the lock-free `ConcurrentHashMap` and a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: If you use e.g. a `ConcurrentHashMap` and one of the `java.util.concurrent` queues, perhaps an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a size of 1, I don't think any additional locking would be required.

Comment: This type of problem is s common EIP, it shouldn't be necessary for user1172468 to re-invent the wheel when others have solved it with thoroughly tested approaches

Comment: I don't think it is a complex enough problem to require a major framework usage, definitely does not merit the downvote.

Comment: I would tend to disagree; while on it's surface it's not terribly complex... But what I see is:

Comment: I would tend to disagree; while on it's surface it's not terribly complex... But what I see is: 1: Manually coding blocking threads and monitor threads, so the coder needs to understand threading pretty well.  2: Resiliency concerns.  3: Scalability concerns.  4: Transactional concerns, he is dealing with queues after all, does he need tx boundaries to ensure only processing  the req/resp one time, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apache Camel for this, a couple of common enterprise integrations apply to this type of use case.

Generally, anything you need to do always fits one or more EIPs, and Camel is like scaffolding to help you code to those well defined and well solved problems.

The best fit here would probably be request/reply

Comment: Just read about `Apache Camel`. Would it be an overkill at all?

Comment: At it's core Camel isn't all that big, it just provides an absurd number of integrations to other technologies

Comment: How many lines of code would call Camel methods to achieve this do you think?

Comment: My other comment outlines my concerns.  If I were coding this for my job, those are all real concerns that need to be addressed, all of which could be solved with camel with about 10-20 lines of XML config.  Now, if this is just for fun, then sure, the academic exercise of coding an EIP yourself might be fun